# Ranking within groups

Tags: stata, ranking, group

I have data in Stata that looks like this -

| State | Year | Revenue | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019 | 30 | 1 |
| A | 2019 | 30 | 1 |
| A | 2019 | 40 | 2 |
| A | 2020 | 45 | 1 |
| A | 2020 | 50 | 2 |
| B | 2019 | 35 | 1 |
| B | 2019 | 45 | 2 |
| B | 2020 | 22 | 1 |
| B | 2020 | 40 | 2 |

The rank column above is what I would like to achieve. Please note that there could be rows like the first and second one that are duplicates in State, Year and Revenue. I want the same rank to be given for these two rows. I basically want ranking within each state and year. I tried `group()` but it did not give the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're at liberty to call this ranking, but it doesn't correspond to

1. what Stata supports with its `egen, rank()` function
2. what it supports with its `egen, group()` function
3. ranking in any strict statistical sense, whereby to a first approximation *n* observations are ranked 1 to *n*, or vice versa.

No matter, as what you want requires only one command line.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str1 state int year byte(revenue rank)
"A" 2019 30 1
"A" 2019 30 1
"A" 2019 40 2
"A" 2020 45 1
"A" 2020 50 2
"B" 2019 35 1
"B" 2019 45 2
"B" 2020 22 1
"B" 2020 40 2
end

bysort state year (revenue) : gen wanted = sum(revenue != revenue[_n-1])

list, sepby(state year)

     +----------------------------------------+
     | state   year   revenue   rank   wanted |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |     A   2019        30      1        1 |
  2. |     A   2019        30      1        1 |
  3. |     A   2019        40      2        2 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  4. |     A   2020        45      1        1 |
  5. |     A   2020        50      2        2 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  6. |     B   2019        35      1        1 |
  7. |     B   2019        45      2        2 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  8. |     B   2020        22      1        1 |
  9. |     B   2020        40      2        2 |
     +----------------------------------------+
```

That is, you bump up the result every time you see a different value. This works for the first observation in any group as the tacit reference to the value in observation 0 results in missing, which is different from the value in the first observation.